How to make external Gdrive user as collaborator
I am using Google API to collect events (such as upload file/share).
I noticed in one log that a user got:
actor_is_collaborator_account: True.
I wonder how to manage this field, all external users set to False.
Example:
{'kind': 'admin#reports#activity', 'id': {'time': '2024-06-09T21:51:57.276Z', 'uniqueQualifier': 'XXX', 'applicationName': 'drive', 'customerId': 'XXX'}, 'etag': '"XXX"', 'actor': {'email': 'michael@xxx.com', 'profileId': 'XXX'}, 'events': [{'type': 'access', 'name': 'edit', 'parameters': [{'name': 'primary_event', 'boolValue': False}, {'name': 'billable', 'boolValue': False}, {'name': 'owner_is_team_drive', 'boolValue': True}, {'name': 'owner_team_drive_id', 'value': 'XXXX'}, {'name': 'owner', 'value': 'Michael - Shared'}, {'name': 'doc_id', 'value': 'XXXX'}, {'name': 'doc_type', 'value': 'unknown'}, {'name': 'is_encrypted', 'boolValue': False}, {'name': 'doc_title', 'value': 'MessageTraceResult (2).csv'}, {'name': 'dlp_info', 'value': ''}, {'name': 'visibility', 'value': 'shared_externally'}, {'name': 'team_drive_id', 'value': 'XXX'}, {'name': 'originating_app_id', 'value': 'XXX'}, {'name': 'actor_is_collaborator_account', 'boolValue': False}]}]}
How do I make a user actor_is_collaborator_account: True?
I've tried to invite users as Manager/Content Manager
I've tried to invite users as Manager/Content Manager

A collaborator account is a non Google user that has been granted access to a Google resource, in this case a shared drive
you can either remove the user or consider changin the shared drive restrictions https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/drives#Drive
restrictions.domainUsersOnly    
boolean

Whether access to this shared drive and items inside this shared drive is restricted to users of the domain to which this shared drive belongs. This restriction may be overridden by other sharing policies controlled outside of this shared drive.

restrictions.driveMembersOnly   
boolean

Whether access to items inside this shared drive is restricted to its members.

